# Is there a way to make a page unaccessible via Google Search but still visitable?

Tags: google-search

It's probably a super basic question but I can only find answers on how to make a site MORE accessible via Google. Like the question says, I want to make a page that won't show up on Google Search because it's a very non-important page but I still want the page to be accessible to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a file called 'robots.txt' in the root of the website hierarchy (example.com/robots.txt).

The file should look something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page_you_want_to_hide.html
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to exclude pages or directories using a robots.txt file. 
More info: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en